# error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘list_node’

Tags: c, header, declaration, typedef

I have a catalog.h file with this

```
typedef struct node* list_node;
struct node
{
    operationdesc op_ptr;
    list_node next;
};
```

and a parser.h with this

```
#include "catalog.h"

int parse_query(char *input, list_node operation_list);
```

Both headers have `#ifndef`, `#define`, `#endif`.
The compiler gives me this error: `expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘list_node’` on the parse_query line.
What's the matter?
I tried to put the typedef in parser.h, and it's fine. Why do I get this error when the typedef is in catalog.h?

Comment: actually, I had an #include "parser.h" in the catalog.h. I removed it, and now it compiles normally... I guess it tried to load parse_query definition before the typedef and struct definition..?

Comment: What exactly does the #ifndef in catalog.h look like? Try cc -E to look at the preprocessor output to see if list_node is really defined at the point of the parse_query line.

Comment: You seem to have two files that `#include` each other. This cannot work because of the include guards. Look at the file after preprocessing and see. Even if you work around the issue somehow, circular dependencies are generally bad regardless and should be eliminated. Try to rearrange your declarations so that there are no recursive `#include`s.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem you're seeing, but typedefs for pointer types are considered to be a bad idea.  Hiding the fact that something is a pointer can lead to subtle errors.  Personally, I'd drop the typedef altogether and replace `list_node` by `struct node*`.

Comment: Where and how's the `operationdesc ` declared ?

Comment: Are you 100% positive that `list_node` is spelled the same way in both catalog.h and parser.h?  If I change the function declaration to `int parse_query(char *input, List_node operation_list);` (uppercase `L`), gcc gives me the same error message you got.  The message indicates that `list_node` (or `List_node` in my modified version) is not a recognized type name.

Comment: Note for future google-ers - If you're like me, you may have shadowed a type definition like `void f(t* t, t* other)`.

Answer (score 6):

The error is this (from your comment):

> I had an #include "parser.h" in the catalog.h. I removed it, and now it compiles normally...

Assuming that `#include "parser.h"` was before the typedef in `catalog.h`, and you have a source file that includes `catalog.h` before `parser.h`, then at the time the compiler includes `parser.h`, the typedef isn't available yet. **It's probably best to rearrange the contents of the header files so that you don't have a circular dependency.**

If this isn't an option, you can ensure that any source files that include these two files include `parser.h` first (or only).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `catalog.h`:

```
typedef struct node_struct {
     operationdesc op_ptr;
     struct node_struct* next;
} node;

typedef node* list_node;
```

Comment: Names that begin with two underscores are reserved, do not use them.