# Why does G_DEFINE_INTERFACE trigger an "expected declaration specifiers" compiler error?

Tags: c, glib, gobject

As part of getting familiar with GObject I'm trying to create a "Hello, world" interface following [the example in the reference manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-interface.html). Here's what I have in `hello_world_if.h`:

```
#ifndef __HELLO_WORLD_IF_H__
#define __HELLO_WORLD_IF_H__

#include <glib-object.h>

G_BEGIN_DECLS

#define TYPE_HELLO_WORLD_IF                (hello_world_if_get_type())
#define HELLO_WORLD_IF(obj)                (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST((obj), TYPE_HELLO_WORLD_IF, HelloWorldIf))
#define IS_HELLO_WORLD_IF(obj)             (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_TYPE((obj), TYPE_HELLO_WORLD_IF))
#define HELLO_WORLD_IF_GET_INTERFACE(inst) (G_TYPE_INSTANCE_GET_INTERFACE((inst), TYPE_HELLO_WORLD_IF, HelloWorldIfInterface))

typedef struct _HelloWorldIf HelloWorldIf; /* dummy object */
typedef struct _HelloWorldIfInterface HelloWorldIfInterface;

struct _HelloWorldIfInterface {
  GTypeInterface parent;

  gchar *(*get_hello)(HelloWorldIf *self);
};

GType hello_world_if_get_type(void);

gchar *hello_world_if_get_hello(HelloWorldIf *self);

G_END_DECLS

#endif /* __HELLO_WORLD_IF_H__ */
```

and in `hello_world_if.c`:

```
#include "hello_world_if.h"

G_DEFINE_INTERFACE(HelloWorldIf, hello_world_if, 0);

static void
hello_world_if_default_init(gpointer g_class) {
  /* Add properties and signals to the interface here */
}

gchar *
hello_world_if_get_hello(HelloWorldIf *self) {
  g_return_if_fail(IS_HELLO_WORLD_IF(self));

  HELLO_WORLD_IF_GET_INTERFACE(self)->get_hello(self);
}
```

But this doesn't compile:

```
$ make
gcc -g -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include   -c -o hello_world_if.o hello_world_if.c
hello_world_if.c:3: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘hello_world_if’
hello_world_if.c:3: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
hello_world_if.c:3: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
make: *** [hello_world_if.o] Error 1
```

From reading other answers here it seems this "expected declaration specifiers" message often means [a necessary header file hasn't been included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001346/error-expected-declaration-specifiers-or-before-list-node) or [has been included too late](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503473/math-h-compilation-error-expected-declaration-specifiers-or-before/9505424#9505424). But I'm not sure how that could be the case here. (Specifically, adding `#include <glib.h>` or `#include <glib-object.h>` to the C file doesn't change anything.)

I must be missing something simple but I just don't see it. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there's a simple explanation: The `G_DEFINE_INTERFACE` macro was [added in GLib 2.24.0](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-announce-list/2010-March/msg00067.html), but I'm using version 2.22.5 (the standard on CentOS 6.3). I'll need to either build and install a newer version of GLib or dig up older reference documentation—[the website](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/) doesn't go back further than 2.26.1.

Comment: The `glib2-devel` package installs the relevant documentation at `file:///usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/index.html`.